# Does this approach have a chance, when I use instance of parent component as property of child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to use instance of parent component in child component via constructor. In other words, I create instance of parent component class as private property and use its properties, methods etc.

Besides that, I can affect to values of parent component properties directly without using Input, Output decorators, event listeners etc.

**Parent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.scss']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  someParentProperty: number = 10;
  
  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnInit() {}
  
  someParentMethod = (num) => num**2;
}
```

**Child**

```
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  someChildProperty: number;
  
  constructor(pc: ParentComponent) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.someChildProperty = this.pc.someParentMethod(this.pc.someParentProperty);
  }  
  
}
```

That's rather comfortable, but I'm not sure, that it's a best practice and right approach.

Could someone explain minuses of this one?

Comment: _"I'm not sure, that it's a best practice"_: it is not. What's the point of defining a _parent_ component if you end up using it as a _child_ component? _"I can affect to values of parent component properties directly without using Input, Output decorators, event listeners"_: and how would this be beneficial? You're just breaking single responsability and encapsulation. Input / output decorators exist in Angular exactly for handling parent/child communication while preserving the principles of a component-based design.

Comment: you should use [Host](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) :  `constructor(@Host() private pc:ParentComponent){}` else you're inject a "component", but not the parent else a new instance. And not, it's not a "best practice" in general. It's used in concrete cases, e.g. a slide in a carousel, a submenu in a menu... in these case there're a strong dependency between parent and children, but even in this cases you should think if it's better use `Output`, `Input` or another way to comunicate to maintain separate the concepts.

Comment: >>What's the point of defining a parent component if you end up using it as a child component? 


If I have a few child components, I'll use parent properties and methods for working with them and not redefine its in each ones, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a service?

So that you can access your required method from both child and parent components.

**E.g:** A common service:

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonService {
    someParentMethod(num) { 
        return num**2;
    }
}
```

At **ParentComponent**:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(commonService.someParentMethod(2));
    }
}
```

You can do the same at **ChildComponent** you can do the same.

It's the best way for sharing.

You can find detail about services [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services).

Comment: Thanks, I know about shared servises, but my question is about other.